# Trransferring image from backened X11 c++ program to Qt application to display that image

Tags: c++, image, qt, x11, xorg

This is the funtion which is taking parent window id of Qt application as a parameter

```
void getImage(Window win){
   d=XOpenDisplay(NULL);
     s=DefaultScreen(d);
     w=XCreateSimpleWindow(d, RootWindow(d, s), 1000, 1000, 100, 100, 14,BlackPixel(d,s),WhitePixel(d, s));
     XMapWindow(d, w);
     XReparentWindow(display, w,win, 50, 50);
     XFillRectangle(d, w, DefaultGC(d, s), 20, 20, 60, 60);
}
```

This is Qt application which is calling getImage(Window win) funtion.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    getImage(w.winId());
    return a.exec();
}
```

I am trying to get image from x11 application and display it on Qt window, but program is crashing at  `XFillRectangle()` and works fine when I comment out `getImage(Window win)` function in Qt application.
Basically I want to do image annotation on Qt window , but annotation overlay frame must come from that x11 running application.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `w.show()`, you just ask window to show, but Qt will wait to event loop execution to display it. You have 2 ways to try:

1. Call `QApplication::processEvents()` after `w.show()`
2. Correct way: subclass QMainWindow and call getImage in overrided function:

   ```
   void showEvent(QShowEvent* showEvent) override;
   ```